# Como insertar un td en una tabla con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes estoy realizando una tabla dinámica que primero llego normalmente con PHPy luego necesito insertar en la ultima posición del tr datos almacenados en una variable json con javascritp en código es el siguiente:

js

```
fin = 0;
$('#tabla_Mtpscajasmn').each(function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").find('td:last').after('<td>'+consola[fin]+'</td>');
  fin++;
});
```

html

```
    <table id="tabla_Mtpscajasmn" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color: #221F1E; color: white;">
            <th style="text-align:center;">Finca</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Año</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Smn</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Cajas</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Amistar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl_Mtps_cajasmn">
           <tr>
              <td>finca</td>
              <td>year</td>
              <td>week</td>
              <td>box</td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>finca</td>
              <td>year</td>
              <td>week</td>
              <td>box</td>
         </tr>
<tr>
              <td>finca</td>
              <td>year</td>
              <td>week</td>
              <td>box</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

resultado esperado

```
<table id="tabla_Mtpscajasmn" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color: #221F1E; color: white;">
            <th style="text-align:center;">Finca</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Año</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Smn</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Cajas</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Amistar</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbl_Mtps_cajasmn">
           <tr>
              <td>finca</td>
              <td>year</td>
              <td>week</td>
              <td>box</td>
              <td>180</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>finca</td>
              <td>year</td>
              <td>week</td>
              <td>box</td>
              <td>160</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>finca</td>
              <td>year</td>
              <td>week</td>
              <td>box</td>
              <td>1660</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

en la tabla no me sale los datos en la ultima columna

Comment: No se si sera esto pero segun la documentación oficial de jquery after -> `Important: If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target except for the last one.`

Comment: simplemente quiero añadir una celda al final del tr

Comment: Prueba con: **$('#tbl_Mtps_cajasmn tr').append('<td>Prueba</td>');**. De todas formas no tiene sentido alguno hacer un **each** de un elemento por **ID**, puesto que solamente vas a tener uno. O yo estoy muy perdido, que puede ser.

Answer (score 0):

puedes obtener tus datos con una función ajax guardándola en una variable, que después puedes recorrer con un foreach e ir creando tu tabla dinámica, ojo, te recomiendo que uses interpolación.

```
$.ajax({
'url': '/cliente/consultar',
'type': 'POST',
'dataType': 'json',
'data': {id : id},
})
.done( function (data) 
{
var tu_tabla = $('table');
var elemento = '';
element+='<tr>'
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
elemento+=`
<td>${value['id']}</td> <--- ojo aquí
`;
});
element+='</tr>'
tu_tabla.append(elemento);
});
```

En la parte señalada puedes construir tu table dinámica haciendo interpolación con los elementos que traes de tu tabla, al hacer uso de ese tipo de comillas puedes hacerlo multilinea.

Comment: amigo eso solo me serviria para un campo pero necesito para una tabla dinamica

Comment: Funciona exactamente de la misma manera, solo depende de que es lo que quieras hacer, voy a editar mi respuesta para que veas una funciona más completa.

Answer (score 0):

Solo es necesario usar el selector de css correcto, Jquery usa CSS para seleccionar el elemento, asi si quieres sacar el ultimo hijo de el tr usa

```
:last-child
$('#tbl_Mtps_cajasmn > tr:last-child').append('');
```